# How to generate Encrypted JWT token in c#

Tags: c#, encryption, jwt

using the below code I could able to generate the encrypted JWT Token. But it is giving 5 parts.  I need only 3 parts. so could any help me in getting the desired code.

```html
  var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: "asds",
                audience: "sds",
                claims: cliams,
                notBefore: DateTime.Now,
                signingCredentials: signingCredentials,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)



                );


            var ep = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.EncryptingCredentials(securityKey1, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityAlgorithms.Aes256KW, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityAlgorithms.Aes256CbcHmacSha512);
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var a = tokenHandler.CreateJwtSecurityToken("issuer", "Audience", new ClaimsIdentity(cliams), DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), DateTime.Now, signingCredentials, ep);
            string tokenString2 = tokenHandler.WriteToken(a);

            Console.WriteLine("Token string: {0}", tokenString);


            var encodedtext = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(a);
```

Comment: How are we meant to know what 3 parts you want?  More information required.

Answer (score 0):

I assume with "parts" you are referring to the compact serialization format... right? Following this assumption, I would advice you to check why you create an encrypted JWT instead of your intended signed JWT.

---

From the [JSON Web Signature (JWS) RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515):

> In the JWS Compact Serialization, a JWS is represented as the concatenation: BASE64URL(UTF8(JWS Protected Header)) || '.' || BASE64URL(JWS Payload) || '.' || BASE64URL(JWS Signature)

---

... resulting in a JWT with three parts and two separators.

From the [JSON Web Encryption (JWE) RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516):

> The JWE Compact Serialization represents encrypted content as a compact, URL-safe string. This string is: BASE64URL(UTF8(JWE Protected Header)) || '.' || BASE64URL(JWE Encrypted Key) || '.' || BASE64URL(JWE Initialization Vector) || '.' || BASE64URL(JWE Ciphertext) || '.' || BASE64URL(JWE Authentication Tag)

... resulting in a JWT with five parts and four separators.